# Android : Text is not Showing in the TextView after applying Async Progress Dialog

Tags: android, progressdialog

I  working on a project in which I am parsing an XML file from the internet and showing its content in the TextView.

**The Procedure:** When I click the button I forward myself to the Prediction class where I am fetching the xml from internet, but now I add the Async Progress dialog into it..
there is no error in the coding but when I run the application in the emulator it shows the catch exception message that is "ERROR" it does not showing the "Information" which is showing earlier before the addition of ASync progress dialog.

```
public class Prediction extends Activity{

static final String baseUrl = "http://astroyogi.in/testandroid/Tarot/Tarot_Android.xml";
TextView tv1;
ImageView iv;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.prediction);
    grabURL("http://astroyogi.in/testandroid/Tarot/Tarot_Android.xml");
    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    }

public void grabURL(String url) {
    new GrabURL().execute(url);
}

private class GrabURL extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog Dialog = new ProgressDialog(Prediction.this);
    static final String baseUrl = "http://astroyogi.in/testandroid/Tarot/Tarot_Android.xml";


    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Downloading source..");
        Dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            URL website = new URL(baseUrl);
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            Handlingpastxml doingWork = new Handlingpastxml();
            xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);  
            xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
            String information = doingWork.getInformation();
            tv1.setText(information);
            }

        catch(Exception e){
            tv1.setText(e.getMessage());

        }
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Plz Help me.. m stuck in this for more than 4-5 hours..

Comment: Post the logcat output whenever you get crash or Force close.

Comment: I am getting this error message when i run the above code ** can't create handler inside thread that has not called looper.prepare() asynctask **

Comment: Yes then solutions are already listed below.

Answer (score 1):

`doinBackGround is non UI thread so never update your UI in this method`

if you want to update `onProgressUpdate or onPostExecute method`

in your case ,Use onPostExecute method

```
String information=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     //your code block
 }

 in doinBackGround method in try block    

 information = doingWork.getInformation();<---Remove `String`

protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Dialog.dismiss();

        if(information!=null&&information.trim().length!=0)
        tv1.setText(information);
    }
```

Comment: tv1.setText(information);  cannot be performed in do in background

Comment: Thanks @Samir Mangrolia..but when i updated my code to urs it is showing an error for getting local variable in doingwork.getInformation... so now what to doo..???

Answer (score 1):

FYI,
you can't do (directly) display/update UI kind of operations inside the doInBackground() method.

### Solution-1:

Remove the below line from doInBackground() and paste it inside the `onPostExecute()`

```
 tv1.setText(information);
```

### Solution-2:

If you want to display/update UI inside the doInBackground() in **anyway**, then write this kind of operations inside the **`runOnUiThread()`** :

```
 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv1.setText(information);
            }
        });
```

Comment: `runOnUiThread()` is not solution there are `onProgressUpdate(for show progress)` and `onPostExecute(for end of doin...)` ,i think no need runUI...

Comment: Check solution-1 above, and agree about onProgressUpdate().

Comment: after applying this code i m getting the eception and the application force close..

Answer (score 0):

It's a question of thread:

While you're in the "doInBackground" method, you're not in the UI Thread anymore. So you can't say "tv1.setText(information);" as it won't update your UI.

"doInBackground" is for your heavy tasks. When these tasks are over, the "onPostExecute" is called. When you're in "onPostExecute", you're in the UI Thread and you can modify your UI as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `new GrabURL().execute(url);` just Write `new GrabURL().execute();`

Because you are already created object in GrabURL.

And other thing is that when you want to update UI in thread we use Handlers so here try to keep in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of following code

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            URL website = new URL(baseUrl);
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            Handlingpastxml doingWork = new Handlingpastxml();
            xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);  
            xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
            String information = doingWork.getInformation();
            tv1.setText(information);
            }

        catch(Exception e){
            tv1.setText(e.getMessage());

        }
        return null;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        Dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

try to do it as follow

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        try{
            URL website = new URL(baseUrl);
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
            Handlingpastxml doingWork = new Handlingpastxml();
            xr.setContentHandler(doingWork);  
            xr.parse(new InputSource(website.openStream()));
            String information = doingWork.getInformation();

            }

        catch(Exception e){
            String information = e.getMessage();

        }
        return information;
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(Void response) {
         tv1.setText(response);
        Dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans @parth but This is not working..  it is showing error in ** return information** and in post execute method

Comment: sorry replace protected void onPostExecute(Void response) with protected void onPostExecute(String response)

Comment: Also instead of declaring String information in doInBackground() method declare information in the main class. @public class Prediction extends Activity{
String information = null;
static final String baseUrl = "http://astroyogi.in/testandroid/Tarot/Tarot_Android.xml";
TextView tv1;
ImageView iv;

Answer (score 0):

you should not update your view from a non UI thread,
in method doInbackground() you can't use tv1.setText(information);

delete

```
tv1.setText(information);
```

from doInbackround()!! and put it in

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
    Dialog.dismiss();
    tv1.setText(information);

}
```

information should be a global variable too